# "God Bubble" - Who teaches/believes such a concept and what is the basic teaching behind the concept?

Tags: charismatic

It's not often I hear a new one, but today one of the people I know mostly on social media posted the following:

> A God bubble needs to comfort and heal [name deleted] while she battles
>   the reoccurance of [disease/condition]. I ask that you
>   please send up your prayers and lift her to the Lord to heal her as
>   quickly as possible and to give her mama and loving caregivers
>   strength to see her through this once again. Blessings of thanks to
>   all of you

This person is known to be among the more Charismatic groups of Christians, and it would not surprise me to learn that the concept of a "God Bubble" is a term commonly used among Charismatic.  If so, I'm looking for examples of teachings on the subject, a general feel for how widespread the belief in a concept of a "God Bubble" is, and which groups teach such a concept.

<sub>*It's obvious the term refers to some sort of protection around an individual.  I'm not as much interested in what the term means, as I am in knowing who teaches this concept, and references to sermons or articles describing the concept and the Biblical basis behind it.</sub>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a Pentecostal of long-standing, mixing with people from various Charismatic backgrounds over the last 25 years, my own experience is of never hearing or reading that phrase used in such a way prior to your citation. On checking a few search results, it looks like it might derived from something like this:

[Bubble With Father God](https://shop.ibethel.org/products/bubble-with-father-god) - *Teresa Liebscher*

[image]

> In the final chapter of the book of Job, God indicates that Job has spoken what is honest and correct about Him. What does a right and honest relationship with God look like? Teresa Liebscher answers that question, and gives you tools to maintain His presence around you like a bubble. It’s His very presence that has a profound effect on not only you but everyone around you!

I've heard a smattering of Bethel teaching over the last decade, but I don't recall ever hearing anything from Teresa Liebscher before; neither do I recall any of their other teachers using the phrase. However I have heard a couple of iterations of their teaching on the manifest presence of God, and although the term itself is novel, I think I can see where it's coming from.

In summary, I'd say the particular usage here is most likely the individual concerned's derived usage of teaching they've received about the manifest presence of God.